# Only one of my templates is getting CSS in Flask

Tags: html, css, flask

I'm using flask to make a webserver, and while trying to edit the CSS of another template other than index.html, the CSS doesn't apply. The file system is as follows:

FlaskApp

```
 app.py

 static
     style
         style.css
 templates
     index.html
     test.html
```

static and templates are both folders. index.html gets the CSS but test.html does not. The link is : "link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='style/style.css') }}". Both html pages have the same link to the css file. What do I have wrong?

Comment: Did you look at the source code? What HTML is being rendered on the test.html page?

Comment: Are both those pages rendered via `render_template`?

Answer (score 0):

A simple `flask` app can have a minimalist structure like this one:

```py
project_folder
    |---------- app.py
    |---------- config.py
    |---------- .env
    |---------- requirements.txt
    |---------- .flaskenv
    |---------- app/
                  |------ routes.py
                  |------ models.py
                  |------ __init__.py
                  |------ forms.py
                  |------ templates/
                              |-------- base.html
                              |-------- index.html
                              |-------- test.html
                  |------ static/
                            |-------css/
                                     |------- styles.css
                            |-------js/
                                     |------- app.js
```

This structure makes it easier to work with the different parts of a flask application following the principle of *separation of concerns*.

Flask has a concept called *template inheritance*. This is where one template can use the layout, styles, features et cetera of another template. In the structure above, I have three templates:

- base.html : this is the parent template from which other templates will inherit
- index.html : child template
- test.html : child template

`base.html` will include a link to the `styles.css` file which is located in the css subfolder within the static folder. Both `index.html` and `test.html` will inherit the `styles.css` link from the `base.html` template.

```html
<!-- base.html -->

{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}

<!-- Title Section -->
{% block title %}
    {% if title %}
        Test | {{ title }}
    {% else %}
        Flask App
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

<!-- Link Styles -->
{% block styles %}
    {{ super() }}
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'css/styles.css') }}">
{% endblock %}


<!-- This is borrowed from Bootstrap -->
<!-- Navbar Section -->
{% block navbar %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Flask App</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">            
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">  
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>                       
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
{% endblock %}
<!-- End of Navbar Section -->

<!-- Your Content Goes Here -->
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">

        <!-- Other templates' content will go here -->

    </div>
{% endblock %}
<!-- End of Your App Content -->
```

Above, `base.html` inherits the styles used by `bootstrap/base.html` using the keyword `extends`. This keyword is used every time you want to inherit another template.

If you look at the `styles` block, you can see the link that points to `styles.css`. That's it!

Now we can make the other two templates to inherit `base.html`.

```html
<!-- index.html -->

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <!-- title -->
                <h1>Home Page</h1>
            </div>                   
{% endblock %}
```

You can see that the keyword `extends` is used, meaning it inherits everything from `base.html`. We can do the same for `test.html`:

```html
<!-- test.html -->

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <!-- title -->
                <h1>Test Page</h1>
            </div>                   
{% endblock %}
```

You can add `class`es and `id`s to your child templates and pass your styles in the `styles.css` file and they will be applied across your application.

These may be a lot of new concepts to you. Take your time to learn them and soon everything will make sense and become easier. As always, check the [flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/) for more specific information.